# Critical Number real life applications

Tags: calculus, derivatives, applications

I've studying a lot Critical Number/Point and I have to give a presentation about it.

I am searching real life applications to explain the concept, but it's difficult to find.

Anyone here can give me some real life applications examples about critical number?

Comment: You want to find the minimum amount tin needed to create a can capable of holding 8 oz. of soup in order to save money when starting up a soup business. Or any other canned food business for that matter.

Comment: Any modern calc textbook should have a section about optimization.  Can't do that without critical numbers.

Answer (score 1):

There are many problems in physics that use this concept. For example, when two atoms come together to form a molecule. They come closer to each other because the energy of the system is smaller if they share electrons. But if they are too close, the electrons cannot screen the nuclei. The two nuclei will repel, so at very short distances the energy is increased. The energy as a function of distance has a minimum (critical point), so the nuclei will be at that particular distance. Google atomic potential.